# replace variable name with the respective variable value

Tags: javascript

I want to make a website in which variable name written in '{{' and '}}' should get the value of variable. For example

```
<body>
hi its is {{ a }}
<script>
var a = me;
</script>
</body>
```

the output should be
hi its is computer

here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    hey it is {{ data[0] }}. how are you. I am {{ data[1] }} years old.
    <script>
        var data = ["computer",'2000'];  
        //the script
        var doc = document.body.innerHTML;
        let length = doc.split('{{').length-4;
        for(let i=1;i<=length;i++){
        let dos = doc.slice(doc.search('{{')+2,doc.search('}}'));
        eval(`sp = ${dos}`);
        document.body.innerHTML = doc.replace(dos,sp).replace('{{','').replace('}}','');
        var sp = '';
    }
        //the end of script
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

output of the above code is:
hey it is computer. how are you. I am {{ data[1] }} years old.
once visit this jsfiddle. Here is my code. https://jsfiddle.net/3ocmkwq2/

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
document.body.innerHTML = doc.replace...
```

updates `document.body.innerHTML`, but does not update the `doc` variable, so this remains as it was before any replacements were made.

So next loop, doc is still the original, so the splice to get `{{ }}` re-gets the `data[0]`.

To fix, update `doc=` after changing the `.innerHTML`

```js
var data = ["computer", '2000'];
//the script
var doc = document.body.innerHTML;
let length = doc.split('{{').length - 4;
for (let i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
  let dos = doc.slice(doc.search('{{') + 2, doc.search('}}'));
  console.log(dos)
  eval(`sp = ${dos}`);
  document.body.innerHTML = doc.replace(dos, sp).replace('{{', '').replace('}}', '');
  
  // update the doc variable
  doc = document.body.innerHTML;
  var sp = '';
}
```

```html
hey it is {{ data[0] }}. how are you. I am {{ data[1] }} years old.
```